# Time quiz count down with quiz end date in database

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a quiz with a count down, Each question takes 15 seconds to answer.

When the user starts a question, I save the `question_id` + the `end_time` which would be after 15 seconds from now.

The table looks like that:

```
             quiz_attempts
________________________________________
| id | user_id | question_id | end_time |
|____|_________|_____________|__________|
| 1  |     1   |      1      | end_time |
|____|_________|_____________|__________|
```

Then when the page is fully loaded, I show a counter for the user which starts from `15` seconds and ends with `0`. And the user has to answer the question within 15 seconds.

```
<span class="counter">15</span>
```

The issue is that the `end_time` would be sooner than the `15` seconds counter shown to the user.

So for example the `end_time` is `12:06:22` and the counter is shown to the user ends `12:06:25`. And it would depend on the internet speed of the user.

So how to time both times so that the `end_time` ends with the front-end counter like `12:06:22` for both?

**I don't want to start with the `end_time` from the database, As I want the page loaded 1st so that the user can start reading and answering the question within 15 seconds not less**

Comment: Not entirely sure why you are storing the end time in the database in the first place - does not seem to be a relevant data that you need to keep around. Anyway, you can trigger saving the end time in the database, once the page finished loading (body onload event or the onload event of any other element you might be dynamically loading into the page).

Comment: @Shadow Because this is one by one questions quiz. Meaning that the user doesn't have to answer all questions at once. He could answer some, Then after a while continue the rest

Comment: + I need to know if the user started a question and didn't answer it

Comment: I think you should revisit your requirements as a lack of answer can indicate that the user started the question, but never answered it, there is no requirement to log when the 15 seconds would expire for answering.

Comment: @Shadow There are 2 approaches for me in this case, 1st is to check `attempts` vs answers, 2nd is when the user returns to the quiz again

Comment: @Shadow By saying "you can trigger saving the end time in the database, once the page finished loading", You mean with Ajax for example, or what?

Comment: Yep, an ajax call could serve as the trigger.